# How can I use mp3 files in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8

in my windows phone gaming apps, I have to use lots of sound. Now I have seen that Windows phone does not support mp3 files. So I need to use the wav files. Any mp3 file which is just 500 kb size in mp3 format, when convert that to ".wav" it becomes min 2.5MB. It's actually eating up my apps size and unnecessarily the size of my apps is getting bigger.

Anyone know how can I use the mp3 file? In my solution I have a Asset folder and inside this folder all the ".wav" files are located.

How I am doing this let me write a code

```
SoundEffect effect;
```

Iinside constructor-

```
{  
   ...
   var soundFile = "Assets/Jump.wav";
   Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(soundFile);
   effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
```

And in the code

```
effect.Play();
```

Is there any better approach. In some thread I come to know that doing this is not a better way coding as it creates object and used up the system space. Please suggest what to do, how do I add mp3 files and write better code for working with sound files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `BackgroundAudioPlayer` to play your wav and mp3 files. `SoundEffect` class cannot play mp3 data

Go through this it's an entire app on it's own.

[Background Audio WP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To use an MP3 file you would have to decode the MP3 into PCM in memory, and use that resulting stream in the SoundEffect.FromStream method.

Another thing you could try is encoding the wav files as ADPCM. This usually compresses the wave file at ratio of 4:1. If you can't use the stream directly, decoding of ADPCM is much more straightforward than decoding an mp3 file.

And one more thing you could try to save space is converting the uncompressed wave files into mono, and a lower sampling rate. You can perform listening tests on the sounds after the conversion to make sure that the loss in quality is acceptable or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but could you provide some link or sample code fro encoding WAV files, that would be great. And how to convert to mono and the lowering sample rate? Please ...